# Change opacity of React Element while scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I am trying to clone tesla website but I am stuck at the point where when a scroll is performed, several **react element's** opacity start *decreasing* and when the scroll is stopped, their opacity is ***1*** again.

Cloned Website: https://tesla-clone-by-dc.netlify.app/

If anyone is unable to understand what I am trying to say kindly refer to images (I have highlighted the elements) and then the real tesla website.

**Image:**

[image: Cloned Website]

Answer (score 0):

To get this behavior you can register for `onscroll` events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll. If you use your browser's developer console to inspect the "Model S" header and then scroll a little, you'll see that the surrounding `<section>` gains a style attribute, like so: `<section class="tcl-hero-parallax__copy reveal" style="--copy-opacity:1.0;">`. If you grab the scroll bar and drag it up and down, you'll see that `--copy-opacity` change between 1.0 and 0 the further down you go.

I'm not sure if there's an alternative solution that only uses CSS, but it seems to me based on the way it updates in frequent, small intervals that they have an `onscroll` listener that then sets that `--copy-opacity` value proportional to how much the page has been scrolled. As for making the opacity go back to 1 at the end of the scroll, that is likely a side effect of how the page "snaps" to the top of the nearest section when you stop scrolling.

Comment: I am able to achieve decrement in opacity when the scroll is performed, but failed to get the max opacity when scrolled is completed.

`$(window).scroll(function(){
   $('.opacity').css("opacity", 1- $(window).scrollTop() / 500)
});`

Comment: You'll want to set opacity back to 1 when the user stops scrolling. There's no "stopped scrolling" event but you can use something like https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce to schedule a function to run at some time after the last scroll event you receive:
`$(window).scroll(function() { _.debounce(function() { /* set opacity to 1 */ }, 100)})`.